# Oracle DBlink able to access all the tables except 1 table

Tags: oracle11g

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ORA-02063: preceding line from dblinkname 00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

Comment: Usually this is a permissions issue.  Ensure that the user connecting to the remote database has appropriate permissions to the table you are interacting with.

Comment: When accessing data over a database link, you identify yourself with target schema's username and password and thus have all privileges to access those objects. I'm not sure I understand what "permissions" you have on your mind, @saritonin. I'm not saying that you're wrong, just that I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: As of the question itself: @Arun, you should provide some more information about what's going on. A SQL*Plus copy/paste demonstration would help.

Comment: @Littlefoot, you don't necessarily have to connect as the user/schema with your target data.  If you're connecting as a different user/schema, you'd need the connection user to have privileges to access the target data.  For example, you may have a "READONLY_USER@REMOTE_DB" account that the database link uses to connect but may be querying data from "MAIN_USER.TABLE@REMOTE_DB"  If it's a frequent task to query tables this way, most of the tables in MAIN_USER may have granted SELECT privilege to READONLY_USER.  If a new table is missed in the privilege grants, you'd see this error.

Comment: Aha. OK; I understand now. Thank you for the explanation, @saritonin